# Imaging microSD w/ NOOBS using rooted android phone with external SD

Tags: noobs, android

I have a LG G3 phone that I rooted, which has an external sd card. When I plug it into my Mac I can adb shell and su without problem but I cannot access it using finder. It's not mounting properly as a USB drive I'm assuming.

I am trying to put NOOBS on to the sdcard but I first need to reformat as FAT32 and then flash it somehow. Any ideas? The phone is pretty janky just but it is rooted so there should be a way.

Comment: You cannot access from the Mac because of `SIP` security restrictions (and the fact `macOS` does not have `ext4` drivers) , you can only access the `FAT` partitions. That does not stop you from formatting the card on `macOS`.